# Meaning of Hamiltonian between two different states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, quantum-states

If we have states $\left | 1 \right>$ and $\left | 2 \right>$, and the Hamiltonian operator $\hat{H}$, what is the meaning of the expression
$$\left< 1 \right | \hat{H} \left | 2 \right >$$

Comment: related: [Off-diagonal matrix elements of the Hamiltonian = transition rate?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229462/) and links therein.

Comment: Thank you. I was asked this today and I just froze and realised I couldn't put it into words.